# How to mark use statements for conditional compilation?

Tags: syntax, rust, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to mark certain includes to only get included on relevant OS's?

For example, can you do something like:

```
#[cfg(unix)] {
    use std::os::unix::io::IntoRawFd;
}
#[cfg(windows)] {
   // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.AsRawFd.html  suggests this is equivalent?
   use std::os::windows::io::AsRawHandle;
}
```

Trying to compile the above code gives me syntax errors (i.e. `error: expected item after attributes`).

I'm trying to patch a Rust project I found on GitHub to compile on Windows (while still making it retain the ability to be compiled on its existing targets - i.e. Unixes & WASM). Currently I'm running into a problem where some of the files import platform-specific parts from `std::os` (e.g. `use std::os::unix::io::IntoRawFd;`), which ends up breaking the build on Windows.

Note: I'm using Rust Stable (1.31.1) and not nightly.

Comment: Yes it is possible, just leave out `{` and `}`. So your example is just a typographical error. Also see https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "unix")]
use std::os::unix::io::IntoRawFd;

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
use std::os::windows::io::AsRawHandle;
```